# Is it still possible to get Diner Dash on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, psn

The IGN page for [Diner Dash](http://ps3.ign.com/objects/143/14322191.html) says it was released for PS3 in November of 2009, but I can't find any information about it in the PlayStation Store or on the PlayStation website (US & UK). Is this game no longer available for some reason? Is there still anywhere to buy a code for it or anything?

I know that some games occasionally get removed from the store for legal reasons or whatever, but does anyone know why this game, specifically, got removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer available - both the PSN and XBLA versions were removed in April of 2011. No reason was ever given, although there were rumors about it having to do with Konami's takeover of Hudson (who produced the PSN and XBLA versions) and Konami not wanting to pay the license fees for Diner Dash.